# gauss.sty and \hline

Tags: gauss

I'ld like to use \hlines in gauss.sty.  Here's a (not) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gauss}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  \hline
  3 & 4 
  \rowops
  \add{0}{1}
\end{gmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

TeX responds:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height     \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.7
```

How can I use horizontal lines within gauss.sty?

EDIT: Dan's solution has the benefit to easily use options as {cc|r|l|r}.  But the parallel gmatrix is out of synch if one uses

```
1 & \dfrac{1}{2}
```

that is, if array's elements are too high.

The pstricks-solution can't easily format the entries (I know, there is hack), but vertical lines are also possible as (faked) \hlines.

Comment: `gmatrix` uses it's own homebrewed alignment algorithm and `\hline` is not supported. No material between rows is allowed.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I'm aware of that fact, hence the question. ;)

Comment: I don't think you can do it without extensive surgery on `gauss.sty`, because it relies on dismantling the built table row by row; material between rows will break the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your desired matrix in an `array` and then place the `gmatrix` next to it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gauss}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
\hline
3 & 4 
\end{array}
\begin{gmatrix}
\\
\rowops
\add{0}{1}
\end{gmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I propose this possibility with `pstricks`. The strategy consists in adding an intermediate row with an empty node in each column, and connecting them with the `\pstLineAB` command from `pst-eucl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gauss}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{gmatrix}
  1 & 2 \vspace{-1ex}\\
\pnode{A} & \pnode{B}\\
  3 & 4
  \rowops
  \add{0}{2}
\end{gmatrix}
\pstLine[nodesep=-0.4em, linewidth=0.4pt]AB{A}{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]